# How to unload a driver that doesn't support any of the usual operations (e.g. Start and Stop) in Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, administration

As an **Administrator**, I want to attach a debugger to a process in Windows, but a low-level driver prevents me from doing this by blocking any attempts.

[image]

Furthermore, the driver blocks any changes to the application's registry settings etc., even for **Local System**. An exception is "Start" (start-up) registry value, but setting this to Disabled (4), makes the system blue-screen on next reboot.

What approach can I take to remove this annoying driver, but keeping the system functional?

Comment: in general you can not unload driver if it not support this. by your description driver faster of all set some callbacks (how minimum for registry). impossible unload driver without unregister this first. how i understand this driver protect this application and special not design for unload. you can remove it registration from registry and reboot. but i guess your application will be not run in such case. so no simply and general solution

Comment: @RbMm - thank you. How do I know, if I've removed the callbacks and other registry dependencies properly, so that the system doesn't stop working on start-up (blue-screen)? How can setting a driver to "Disabled" make the system blue-screen?

Comment: but how you plan at all remove callbacks ? no any general solution. you need reverse engenire this driver for decide how off it

Comment: @RbMm - thank you. But can you explain why it doesn't work to set the driver to "Disabled"? Regarding callbacks, here you mean hooks, right? But if the driver is never started, it should not be able to set any hooks.